# How to install webpack? When I installed, I encountered this error and didn't know how to fix it

Tags: web, webpack

- Version node: v8.15.1
- Version npm : 6.4.1
- when running the installation command: 
  sudo npm install --save-dev webpack

  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSEBM.png)
- As a result, I still have the test installed
- Please help me, thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the "package.json" file in the home/framgia directory.

Enter that directory through a terminal and try running "npm init" first. It will prompt you with a few different options for the project and then generates the package.json file.

Using the "--save-dev" flag saves a reference in package.json under dev dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

First in the image you can evidence that doesnt existe package.json, so are you in the project folder?, if you are there create the package.json open the console and type `npm init -y`  enter and try to install again

Comment: Thank you very much. I did it